# What is meant by the "left" and the "right"?

Tags: parties, terminology, policy

When discussing political issues and parties, I often hear mention of a party being "left", "centre-left", "right" or "extreme right". In broad terms, what do these designations mean?

Comment: The fact that someone speaking uses "extreme right" but not "extreme left" should be a clear indication that the terms used are extremely subjective and in the eye of the beholder. 95% of people consider themselves politically moderate.

Comment: The list including "extreme right" was meant to be just examples, as the "extreme left" certainly does exist - Communism is considered far- or extreme- left

Comment: Google has  4,550,000 results for "Extreme right politics" and  1,360,000 for "extreme left politics"

Comment: In Europe, "left" tends to mean the same as "socialist/socialdemocratic" and everything else gets lumped together as "right".

Comment: maybe we now need a 2d model (left front, right back) or even a 3d model (left front top, right back bottom) or even a 3d axis model (5 left, 3 back, 8 top).

Comment: @DVK: The remaining 5% is probably a good definition of "extreme". Problem is most people think that the 20-30% at the other end of the spectrum are "extreme" :D

Comment: @KinjalDixit: https://www.politicalcompass.org splits politics up into a 2D plane: authoritarian-libertarian, and left-right (which is a bit vague, I personally associate it with collectivist vs. individualist).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The standard terms of left and right politics originate from the seating arrangement of the French National Assembly of 1789. They are often considered overly simplistic for today's complex political landscape.

In the 1789 at the French National Assembly the First Estate (noblemen) sat on the right side and the Third Estate (revolutionaries) sat on the left side. Thus, the left wing of the room was more liberal, and the right wing was more conservative.

Today you often use the terms left or extreme-left to describe social and progressive measures and right or even extreme-right the more conservative and nationalistic approaches. Those terms as I stated in the first paragraph however are too simplistic for a modern world where libertarians are often very progressive (left) on social issues such as gay marriage but are fiscally very conservative (right).

Comment: Therefore, the [Nolan Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nolan_Chart) is popular among libertarians. The chart tries to characterize political positions on a two-axis model, one axis being "social authoritarian vs libertarian", the other "economically left vs right".

Comment: @cls: And two dimensions is twice as good as one, but since once dimension is near useless.... :-) The Nolan chart also is very bad because it's still based on the concepts of left and right, which mean nothing. So in fact it only really has one dimension as opposed to zero. Which of course can be claimed to be infinitely better. ;-)

Comment: @cls: No sorry, I was thinking of the political compass, not the Nolan Chart. The Nolan Chart is OK. It actually has two dimensions.

Comment: Note that "progressive" is no more definitive then "left", and "conservative" adds little more than "right" unless applied to specific question (i.e. gay marriage or raising taxes) but in these questions the same person can be conservative and not conservative at the same time.

Comment: Imho this has been dealt with in the last paragraph where I exactly explain what you state in your comment…

Comment: Gay marriage has nothing to do with left-right destinction. It is a US invention that so-called "left" support feminism and gay rights so to divert attention from economic issues and make the "left" inappropriate for normal people. In the USSR homosexualism was punished by a term in prison.

Comment: Actually it is not from the national assembly but from the constitutional meetings, in the "salle de manege royal". 11 september 1789 There was a walking referendum, where people were asked if they  were in favour of keeping or rejecting certain privileges in the new French state.
The first question was: "Should the king retain the right to stop a newly voted law by his veto. Those who are in favour, please place yourself at the right side of the hall, those who are against please go to the left side of the hall" Heads were counted. Essentially the left side was to abolish the privileges.

Answer (score 38):

To quote from my own [answer on History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/what-are-the-counterarguments-to-calling-german-nazism-a-right-wing-movement), the terms "left" and "right" have no objective meaning in today's global politics (unlike their historical usages covered by other answers) - they are 100% subjective, AND extremely varied across polities even when attempted to be used objectively.

To give some examples of complete inconsistencies:

- In post-USSR Russia communist hardline parties are considered "Right Wing" and pro-Western economically liberal ones (e.g. pro-capitalist) are "Left Wing".
- A somewhat related but separate problem is historical drift. As a classical example, originally support for laissez-faire capitalism and free markets were counted as being "on the left"; today in most Western countries these views would be characterized as being "on the right".
- Gay Rights are commonly considered a property of the Left Wing (and opposition to them Right Wing). Leaving aside the usual imprecision of lumping together people with diverse views with a simplistic label ("right wing" libertarians in USA are strongly anti-gay-discrimination), let's not forget that SA was strongly pro-homosexual all the way to the top ([Rohm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_R%C3%B6hm)). Sturmabteilung wasn't exactly an example of what people commonly refer to "left wing", though technically speaking, being against the established order, they should be. Also, many Marxist/leftist governments (e.g. USSR, Cuba) were strongly anti-gay for a variety of reasons, some of which were... "being gay is a bourgeoisie thing".

It's very hard to define "Right Wing" today, especially since most people referred to as "Right Wing" today not only have nothing in common with the historical origin of the term (French Monarchists after French Revolution), but don't have much common politically with each other aside from opposing some or all of the policies labeled "Left Wing", and even that for a wide variety of reasons.

- People lump together on the right anyone from staunchly anti-religious "sex maniac" Ayn Rand to "Family Values" Christian fundamentalists some of whom literally wouldn't agree with Randian Objectivists about anything other than statists/Communists being a common opponent.
- Even single-country party affiliations don't help much either, for a variety of reasons. "USA Republicans are Right Wing" is a nice soundbite, except you just lumped together Ron Paul, Pat Robertson, Martin Luther King Jr., Trent Lott and Abraham Lincoln. Again, not really all THAT much in common between the 5 of them.

Comment: It's hard to define right-wing, not because it has nothing in common with the historical term, but because the opinions/ideologies regarded as "right" have nothing in common with *each other*.

Comment: And parties shift their positions over time. There were a lot of positions taken by both parties that would embarrass them today.

Comment: But generally aren't Communists considered leftists?

Comment: @adithskv - They like to consider themselves leftists - especially when they arbitarily decide that fascists were "rightists". However, 100% of attempted states governed by Communist parties ended up being far closer to right wing totalitarianism than theoretical left wing communism.

Comment: A good example of right wing parties being different is the difference between Australia and the USA.  In Australia, the major right wing party were the advocates and implementers of gun control policies.  The left wing party were the ones who floated the dollar and dropped the tariff walls of the 60s and 70s.  In fact tariffs in and of themselves are contentious amongst the right in the USA.  Until 2016, tariffs were an anathema to right wing beliefs.  Now, the right are the ones who are trying to bring them in.

Comment: This one seems reasonably consistent: "left" is people who value equality, and "right" is people who value hierarchy. Hence, for example, support for capitalist free market was once thought to make everybody equal, so people who liked equality supported it, but now we see how it causes hierarchies and people who like hierarchies support it. Ditto for Soviet communism. Doesn't explain the homosexuality thing though.

Comment: @user253751 - that one is actually unreasonably wrong. In a society with more equality, "left" would be people fighting for more inequality and "right" (or conservatives) would be fighting to preserve equality status quo, using standard definition.

Comment: @user4012 What you say is unreasonably wrong. In which society with equality do the "left" fight for inequality and the right fight for equality?

Answer (score 19):

These terms vary greatly by country. In the US, currently "left" is identified with people that believe in:

- Redistribution of wealth by means of taxation and welfare spending
- Expansive treatment of rights - i.e. right to housing, right to specific level of income, right to medical care, etc.
- Positivist approach to rights (government can create or destroy rights)
- Laissez-faire governmental approach to social life and public morals
- Government control for the behaviors that are considered harmful to the society, and governmental encouragement of the behaviors that are considered beneficial for the society
- More diplomatic and appeasing approach to international conflicts
- Primacy of international law and mores over the national peculiarities and traditions
- Collectivism more than individualism

On the other hand, the "right" is identified with:

- Laissez-faire approach to economic activity
- Restricting the role of the government to ensuring economic activities are not violating the rules of "fair play" but not promoting any specific goals or activities
- Private responsibility for one's welfare
- Governmental and public control over morals and social life
- Great reverence to tradition, religion, etc.
- Negativist approach to rights (rights are absence of violation of small number of principles)
- More forceful and aggressive approach to international matters, including intervention in places that do not directly influence internal US matters
- Nationalism and primacy of national law and mores over the international ones
- Reducing taxation and discouraging using taxation for governmental projects beyond defense, internal policing and such
- Individualism more than collectivism

You may notice that some of these items seem somewhat contradictory or inconsistent, and some are vague. This is what it is - people do hold contradictory or inconsistent beliefs and some of their positions are vague or fluid. You may also notice many people that vote right hold some left views, and many people that vote left have right views. That happens a lot.

About the "extreme" and "far" labels - except for a small variety of cases (like neo-nazis, anarchist gangs and such) they usually mean exactly nothing. In 99.9% cases this label would be applied by a politician to an opposing politician and would mean no more than "this is a very bad man, you should vote for me, not for him".

Comment: Is increasing alimony and making quotas for women a left or right thing?

Comment: @Anixx increasing alimony would be neutral since it depends on one's opinion about how much it costs to raise a child, which is not really ideological. Quotas are definitely left thing, since it is a government intrusion into private economic activity to promote particular behavior.

Comment: The 3rd point on the "right" shows a lack of understanding and a leaning towards the common narrative.  It should read, "Private, family, community, local and state responsibility for one's welfare".  The next point, "Governmental control over morals and social life" would be better placed under the left.  The right felt gay marriage should be left to the states but left appointed judges have now deemed that all states must abide by their moral interpretation of what is right when it comes to gay marriage. Same could be said about abortion.

Comment: @PostImpatica community, local, and state responsibility for one's welfare is "left".

Answer (score 14):

Another interpretation of left and right that one may come across relates to the distribution of power. In a simplified way, the right is associated with a top-down power structure, whereas the left is associated with an egalitarian distribution of power. This distribution fits with what most people would associate with *left* and *right* in daily life.

Right-wing ideologies favour power structures that are top-down. This can be power by the church, the state, corporations, etc. The most extreme example of this are extreme-right ideologies such as fascism, which is the ideology of anti-democracy. Depending on interpretation of *power*, also models that allow for very large corporate freedom (such as anarcho-capitalism/libertarianism) are far right, because corporations are not normally democratically controlled. See also [wage slavery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_slavery).

The left, then, favours egalitarian power models. As society originates in top-down power models, such ideologies are often radical or revolutionary in nature. In its extreme, this can be expressed by the utopian German (double negative) slogan *Keine Macht für Niemand*, which literally means *no power for nobody*. The ideal expressed by this phrase is that nobody holds power over anybody else. This is not limited to politics, but also to other aspects of life, most notably at work. In such a distribution of power, work is not associated with shareholder-owned corporations, but with worker-owned cooperatives.

The division above is consistent with the traditional distribution of ideologies in left and right. Left-wing is big government and right-wing is small government, because in our society the government is more or less the only institution under some democratic control, so if power is transferred from a democratically controlled government to uncontrolled corporations, power becomes more top-down; if power resides with a democratically controlled government, power becomes more egalitarian. Of course, this breaks down if a government is not democratically controlled.

In this model:

- *Fascism* is far-right because it explicitly strives for a authoritarian distribution of power.
- *Anarcho-capitalism* can be considered far-right because it takes away almost all power from  democratically controlled organs, but whether this leads to a vertical distribution of power depends on where this power goes. If this power is taken by shareholder-owned corporations, it means power distribution becomes more vertical.
- *Theocratic* systems favour a strong power for religious institutes. I think those are mostly hierarchical in nature; I'm not aware of strongly democratic religions. That would put theocracies on the right (see also *conservative* below).
- *Communism* is far left in theory, because it puts workers in control of the factories and of the state. In practice it turned out quite authoritarian, so rather right-wing and in its extremes alarmingly close to its ideological opposite, fascism. However, even if the situation turned out similar in practice, the propaganda, what the nations *claimed* to be, was still vastly different between the worst era of Stalinism and fascist states.
- *Socialism* and *Social-democracy* tend to empower workers, but to a lesser degree than *communism*, and are therefore less far left on the scale.
- *Anarcho-syndicalism* is perhaps the most far left, approaching the utopia where nobody holds power over everybody else, by putting the means of production in hands of democratic councils, e.g. factories are owned by the workers etc. The power of the state is minimal, but contrary to *anarcho-capitalism*, this power is transferred to small-scale democratically owned organs, not to huge multinational shareholder-owned corporations.
- *Conservative* ideologies tend to the status quo. The status quo is usually a quite top-down division of power, so those can be considered right-wing.
- *Progressive* and *revolutionary* ideologies favour to change society. Most of those ideologies are on the left, such as *communism* and *anarcho-syndicalism*. However, *nazism* was also revolutionary in nature, although left-wing revolutionaries may choose to use the term *reactionary*, as *nazism* was also strongly *anti-revolutionary* in nature.

Now this interpretation is not unique, but I think it works well to describe most important ideologies. Your mileage may vary :)

Comment: Given the fact that USSR - arguably the most left-wing state observed in recent history (and lauded as such by progressives) had orders of magnitude worse power structures AND in-egalitarianism than typical Western capitalist democracies - BOTH on a state level AND work level - this answer is 100% wrong from the get go. The "right" as you define it is in no way, shape or form associated with "top-down power structure", given historical realities.

Comment: The progressives may be CLAIMING to be egalitarian in their own mind, but when they get what they want, the practical end result is inevitably the worst power inequality possible, in a closed system.

Comment: By the way, Mussolini (who was far more of an expert on fascism than you or I are), explicitly noted that he was building fascism as a repudiation of BOTH left and right as he understood them.

Comment: Just for reference, a typical large factory boss in USSR (even after Stalin), or in China, has infinitely more power over random worker than any CEO of a western company. So much for socialism (which you acknoweledge being on the left) having anything to do with LESS top down power at work.

Comment: @DVK, the USSR has never been a communist nation and was certainly not left-wing state, nor is it lauded by progressives. That's why I made a difference between "communism in theory" and "communism in practice". The USSR claimed to be democratic and communist, but both were big lies. I don't think any socialist state has ever existed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work at all. For example, modern left is often promoting federal powers over state powers, which is in no way egalitarian, and may members of the Republican party, which is universally considered "right", believe in reducing the size of the government and restricting its power. How big government is equal distribution of power is beyond comprehension - did you see any big government in action? Do you sincerely believe all citizens under such setup have equal power? The only equality you can achieve with such setup is equal powerlessness before the bureaucracy.

Comment: I was not aware that the modern left in the US promotes that. In Europe, the left promotes the exact opposite, less power in Brussels because it lacks democratic control. I sincerely believe that citizens have more power in the case of big government than in the case of big corporations, because governments can be sent home in elections with one man, one vote, whereas in corporations, the situation is one dollar, one vote, which is considerably less democratic. Therefore, a big government is a more equalised distribution of power.

Comment: @DVK the USSR was well surely Socialist. There was virtually no private property on the means of production and the income was very egalitarian: the income difference between factory director and a worker could be less than 2 times (300 vs 500 rubles a month at 1970s). The highest possible income was about 5000 rubles a month for Brezhnev himself.

Comment: @DVK The control of the factory director over workers was nearly the same as in the west and much smaller than of a factory owner in the west. He could not legally fire anybody at will. He was under strict control from behind, including things like what the factory produces (which is usually cannot be affected by the workers in the west).

Comment: @Anixx Is that theory or practice you're talking about?

Comment: @gerrit what you are asking about?

Comment: There are quite a few varieties of Protestantism in the US that are non-hierarchical.

Comment: Well said.  But the western world is best described as a corporatocracy, not a democracy, today.

Answer (score 13):

During the French revolution the most radical politics were sitting on left site, the most conservative on the right. So traditionally the conservatists (the ones who want to preserve existing order) are considered rightists, while the people who want to change it are considered leftists.

This divide functions quite well in USA, where rightists (conservatists) are fighting for traditional American values such as right to possess arms and corporation-friendly law.

In Europe the situation is much more complicated. Where the Nazi rightists or leftists? They wanted to overthrow the existing order. But they are considered rightists, because they glorified the right of the strong over the weak. In Europe someone who cares for weak and want to protect them from stronger is considered leftist.

There comes also the attitude towards religion. The politics who consider religion as basis of social relations are considered rightists and those who oppose - leftist. However, there are christian-socialist parties which are both religious-driven and concentrated on the poorest and the weakest. On the other side we have radical liberal parties, which are both against religion and for the lower taxes and low social expenses, which are hard to classify as leftists or rightists.

Comment: This is even more complicated. In russia, the pro-market people are "left" and hardline pro-communist people are "right".

Comment: There is a reason why I reflected mostly on the historical nature of the terms and did not try to make statements about the current situation which is much more complex ;)

Comment: @user4012 which is consistent with the left=equality, right=strong hierarchy view. Surely if they ever get a market they will find out markets are not as equal as they would like.

Comment: @user253751 - you keep using that word, but i don't think it means what you think it means. If you believe left is for equality, you should go read Orwell's 1984, followed by a set of reputable acounts by people who lived in USSR, Venezuela etc.... Some animals... well are just more equal than others. In a very big way, far surpassing the worst Gini coefficient in the market economy, in practice. After all, infinity is always bigger than even 1000.

Comment: @user4012 I don't know why you'd suggest looking at right-wing places to find out what happens in left-wing places.

Comment: @user4012: Orwell was a lifelong leftist. Famously, he went to Europe to shoot fascists. His novels "1984" and "Animal Farm" were descriptions of totalitarianism and right-wing rhetoric respectively. One of Orwell's lessons might be appropriate for you: Don't believe governments when they describe themselves!

Comment: It's not the "change" that makes a left. It's the progressism toward enlightment concepts. Change to go back to royalism, or some fantasy imperial age, like a reich, is rightist by definition of conservatism. Center/Right is statu quo, right is a bit back, extreme right is back to pre-revolution eras; or even fantasized good old something (usually very vertical glorious something).

Answer (score 3):

While these criteria are normative, there are solidly defended norms out there for these meanings.  A number of the other current norms have been covered, so I'm going to concentration on the broadly Marxist normative system for these terms that arises out of the issue of control over productive property in society.

Such a schema results is a very rapid classification:
Those acting or claiming to be in favour of workers control of production: Left
Those acting or claiming to be opposed to workers control of production: Right
Those acting or claiming to be indifferent or deliberately seeking an accommodation between worker and boss that significantly empowers workers: Centre

In this scheme almost every political party lies between right-centrism and the far, but not revolutionary, right.  Most current parliamentary "Communist" parties, such as Eurocommunism or most self-announced "revolutionary" Trotskyite parties are actually right-centrist.  Their platforms describe minor adjustments to capitalism in favour of "fairness" or "it working better."

This comes across a number of problems in the post-1789 world, and can't functionally apply to a pre-1789 world (The Party and the Faction, for example); it pre-supposes a bourgeois triumph over the aristocracy in terms of the dominant mode of production and property form.

So what about reactionaries?  Most 19th century reactionaries were supporting a kind of state led capitalist development, much like the fight over Corn between Tory and Whig.

The other major problem is the difference between ideology and practice by political parties.  The simplest Marxist way to deal with the Bolshevik parties is to observe the vigorous critique of their substitutionalism prior to 1917—a large number of people knew what this party was—and the fight over what a ruling Bolshevik Party would look like, worker or boss, between 1917 and 1921.  More interesting is the long term collapse to the right of Labourism; from a right-centrist to a centre-right movement, while there are some delightful early marxian analyses ("I believe the worker and their boss should keep their present station" IWW, "Bump me into parliament"), this tends to submerge the long march towards Blair of the UK party.

tl;dr:  These meanings are dependent on a theoretical perspective, media commentators usually fail to announce their theoretical perspective, understanding the variety of theoretical perspectives present can let you discover which theory the analyst is using, above is an example of the Marxist theoretical perspective on left/right.

Comment: A little too long winded IMHO but quite precise nevertheless. +1

Comment: There is a balance between waffle and precision that needs to be struck.  I think it would help in general if we announced the perspective of our answer, "Within Neo-Realist international relations..."; "Within 'Workerist' Marxism..." etc. to clarify both the term sets and the limitations on the answer we provide.

Answer (score 2):

A great visualisation of the left vs. right concept can be found here:

Left vs. right visualisation (by David McCandless): http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/left-vs-right-world/

Comment: Welcome to Politics!  We typically frown on naked links - you never know when they are going to disappear.  I would invite you to edit this into a better answer, then flag me to put it back up!

Comment: This is ingenious. I wonder how accurate it is.

Comment: @Slazer agreed. I like how many of the terms on the left and right sound similar on first reading.

Comment: This is a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lose all hope upon entering the doors of categorization because you will leave the perspective of the whole ---how ever perplexing--- behind!

After this warning, i may confess that for this kind of questions i usually fall back to notes i took during a course of latin american history back in 1993.

So my answer to you in a nutshell is
**historically**: "right wing means monarchist, while left wing means revolutionary" and
**actually**: "right wing means conservative, while left wing means progressive".

To analyse social movements and ideologies you can add other axes to the historical one, e.g economic (all between socialism and capitalism) and politic (all between anarchism and authoritarianism). This way you may get a better picture of the whole.

Comment: please note that you can be more historically exact by replacing the term "revolutionary" with "republican", but i am afraid this could drive US natives into craziness. And i really dont want to be blamed for such things

Comment: if you are at the bar and want to categorise people around you on these terms, then you could ask them what they think about poor people claiming not to have enough bread. If they say "well they should eat cake and shut up", then they are right wing. Else, if they say "lets cut the head of those cake eating assholes", then they are left wings. In most cases you will not know what to do. Please understand my sarcasm. You have to be drunk to play this game, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

"Left-wing" refers to ideas, parties or people which favour increased equality or decreased hierarchy. "Right-wing" refers to ideas, parties or people which favour decreased equality or increased hierarchy.

This definition does explain why support for free markets used to be left and is now right. At first, the idea of free markets was competing against the ideas of monarchy and feudalism - very strong hierarchies indeed. Transitioning to free markets makes people more equal - in the beginning. Once it was discovered that free markets tend to re-consolidate wealth and power, the right wing enjoyed this and wanted to continue markets on their path, while the left wing wanted to fix the problem, hence becoming pro-not-entirely-free-market.

The extremes are also easy to understand with this definition: extreme left is anarchism where everyone is perfectly equal (although it would not work out that way in practice) because nobody has specific rights, or communism which is essentially "anarchism but if we find a way to make it work". Dictatorships and ethnostates are extreme right because of the strong hierarchies.