# How to find out whether you're on the left or right?

Tags: ideology

According to [this](http://politicalcompass.org/test) test, I'm a center-left libertarian. Is this accurate? Do you know any other methods?

Comment: Left/right is an extremely simplistic approach to politics.

Comment: I found it reasonably accurate for myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do you know any other methods?

Yes. As a matter of fact, the single-dimension left-right continuum is a singularly crappy way of describing one's political views. This was covered on Politics.SE in ["What is meant by the “left” and the “right”?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/103/115) and on [History.SE discussing whether Nazism was 'right wing'](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/what-are-the-counterarguments-to-calling-german-nazism-a-right-wing-movement/1104#1104)

Most modern advanced classifications use schemes with at least 2 variables/factors to describe political orientation.

**The various methodologies are very thoroughly described in the ["Political spectrum "Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_spectrum)**.

One of the popular ones is [Nolan chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_spectrum#Nolan:_economic_freedom.2C_personal_freedom) - if your main interest is finding a quiz to label yourself politically, google for that term. Another one is "Political Compass" one - as a matter of fact, that's the one driving the test your question linked to.

The pros and cons of Nolan chart vs the others listed in the Wiki is a topic for debate, but pretty much any of them is orders of magnitude better than "left-right", whose main purpose in modern politics is largely "how can I better equate my political opponents to some historical monster".

Answer (score 6):

Being left or right were obvious when being right was being for monarchy and being left was being for republic. This was the single criterion.

Now there are two big factors for distinguishing between the left and the right: the attitude to the economic freedom and social policy and the attitude to religion and conservatic values. This two factor made 4 major political options, 2 of them hard to describe as right or left.

For example, in Poland we have PiS, the conservatist described as the right wing. They are for teaching the religion in schools and against the homosexual marriages etc. But they are for the social state: the country should protect the poor and week from the rich and strong, which is considered leftist. So, is this rightist or leftist party?

I personally want no longer to describe myself as rightist or leftist. This terms are too primitive to describe current political situations.